# How to remove the Cutout in the BottomAppBar when hiding a FAB?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-jetpack

I have a FAB in my layout that is anchored to the BottomAppBar. On certain screens, I want to display the FAB (and the cutout), on other I want it gone.

[this](https://github.com/SennaGehenna/Random_Tables/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) is my layout containing the FAB and BottomAppBar.
[this](https://github.com/SennaGehenna/Random_Tables/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/sennagehenna/randomtables/ui/base/BaseFragment.kt) is my BaseFragment, where I handle whether or not the FAB should be visible.

My app is built in a way, where the fab isn't visible on the first screen.

When I use View.GONE for my visibility, the fab and cutout are correct on screens WITH a fab, but on screens WITHOUT a fab, the cutout remains.

When I use View.INVISIBLE for my visibility, the fab is correct but the cutout doesn't exist on screens WITH a fab, but on screens without a fab, both are correct.

Comment: just use `fab.hide()`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I love you. If you want, you can post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `BottomAppBar` and a `FloatingActionButton` just use:

```
fab.hide()
```